# How to publish magento 2 free extension on magento connect

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to publish my magento2 extension on magneto connect.
Can any one help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research? A Google query for `How to publish magento 2 free extension on magento connect` seems to yield some results?

Comment: Yes i do . but still not find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below all link have explain how to upload m2 extension kindly refer that

https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/How-to-publish-an-extension-in-the-official-Magento-2-extensions/m-p/22633#M89

https://community.magento.com/t5/Building-Extensions/How-can-I-upload-a-Magento-2-extension/td-p/23507

https://magento.com/blog/technical/magento-20-extension-upload-validation-tool